# How can I remove the error "Warning: React does not recognize the mock prop on a DOM element." when using useFormContext

Tags: reactjs, testing, react-hooks, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am using useFormContext in a component in react and when i run the tests with react testing library I am getting error warnings such as

```
console.error
  Warning: React does not recognize the `mockResolvedValueOnce` prop on a DOM element.
  Warning: React does not recognize the `mockRejectedValueOnce` prop on a DOM element.
```

Here is the code of my component

```js
const TextField: React.FC<OptionsField> = ({
  name,
  value,
  placeholder,
  label,
  required,
  type,
  disabled,
  fieldCaption = "",
  autoComplete = "off",
  customProps = {},
}) => {
  const methods = useFormContext();
  const [currentValue, setCurrentValue] = useState(value);
  const [status, setStatus] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    methods.clearErrors(name);
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [status]);

  const validateText = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const text = e.target.value;
    text !== "" ? setStatus("writing") : setStatus("not writing");
  };

  const emptyFieldWhenRequired =
    methods.formState.errors[name] &&
    methods.formState.errors[name].type === "required";

  const valueNotChanged = currentValue === value;

  const errorStyle =
    emptyFieldWhenRequired && (currentValue === "" || valueNotChanged)
      ? "input-error"
      : "";

  const caption = fieldCaption && (
    <span className={fieldStyles["field-caption"]}>{fieldCaption}</span>
  );

  const requiredMessage = emptyFieldWhenRequired &&
    (currentValue === "" || valueNotChanged) && (
      <span className={styles["error-text"]}>Este campo es requerido</span>
    );

  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <label>{label}</label>
      <input
        {...methods.register(name, { value, required })}
        className={`${styles.input} ${styles[errorStyle]}`}
        defaultValue={currentValue}
        type={type}
        placeholder={placeholder}
        disabled={disabled}
        autoComplete={autoComplete}
        onChange={(e) => {
          const value = e.target.value;
          setCurrentValue(value);
          methods.formState.errors[name] && validateText(e);
          methods.setValue(name, value);
        }}
        {...customProps}
      />
      {caption}
      {requiredMessage}
    </div>
  );
};
```

and this is my test file

```js
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";
import TextField from "../TextField";
import { fireEvent, screen, waitFor } from "@testing-library/react";

const mockSubmit = jest.fn();

jest.mock("react-hook-form", () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual("react-hook-form"),
  useFormContext: () => ({
    register: () => jest.fn(),
    handleSubmit: () => mockSubmit,
    errors: () => jest.fn(),
    formState: { errors: {} },
    clearErrors: () => jest.fn(),
    setValue: () => jest.fn(),
  }),
}));

describe("TextField", () => {
  const setup = () => {
    return render(
      <TextField
        label={"Mock TextField"}
        required={true}
        placeholder={"Mock Placeholder"}
        type={"text"}
        value={"mock value"}
        name={"mock name"}
      />
    );
  };

  it("renders TextField without problem", () => {
    const view = setup();
    expect(view).toMatchSnapshot();
  });

  it("simulates change on input", async () => {
    setup();
    const input = screen.getByPlaceholderText("Mock Placeholder");
    fireEvent.change(input, {
      target: { value: "Mock something" },
    });
    await waitFor(() => {
      expect((input as HTMLInputElement).value).toBe("Mock something");
    });
  });
});
```

I have tried mocking the `console.error = jest.fn()` in the `setupTests.js` file as well as in the component test file but it doesn't work.

I have also tried the `--silent` flag but is not working as well.

I also have errors with `window.scrollTo` and `env=jsdom` doesn't work, but mocking the function in the component seems to do the job.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out I needed to mock the `console.error` on each test file as well as in their parent components. I added the following to every required test file:

```js
  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.spyOn(console, "error");
    // @ts-ignore jest.spyOn adds this functionallity
    console.error.mockImplementation(() => null);
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    // @ts-ignore jest.spyOn adds this functionallity
    console.error.mockRestore();
  });
```

I know I got this from someone here on stackoverflow but I can't find the post